# AutoHotkey - (Effectively) Store information

Tags: dll, store, autohotkey, ini

I have always been using `.ini` files to store information generated by my AutoHotkey scripts, hiding them with `FileSetAttrib` afterwards.`.ini` files are great, my only concern is that the user finds the file and alters the information stored in it.

I remember reading something about `.dll` files and `Data Streams`, but I do not know where or how to start, as there aren't that many "tutorials" or documentation articles.

How would you guys approach this, when trying to store information that the user should not be able to change?

Comment: Users will always be able to modify the data depending on how resourceful they are. Have you considered compression, encryption/encoding, custom file structure, hidden locations? Using DLLs would require resource editing. That doesn't seem like an optimal solution.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean by `compression, encryption/encoding, custom file structure, hidden locations`. Could you please elaborate? I'm pretty sure there is a way to hash information using AHK, so I could look into that..

Comment: I meant modifying the save data into a way that the structure doesn't seem obvious to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encrypting settings with AutoHotkey would not have much point too: the effort is not worth it in this case.

I suggest simply encoding the settings into something not too obvious. Keep in mind that if a user wants to change something, assume that they will be able to (depending on how resourceful they are). Something like Base64 should suffice your needs.

### Example script

Using this library: [base64.ahk](https://github.com/jNizM/AHK_Scripts/blob/master/src/encoding_decoding/base64.ahk)

```
;Say you have a `decodefile()` and `encodefile()` function:

#Include base64.ahk
decodefile(filepath) {
  FileRead, rawData, %filepath%
  decoded := b64Decode(rawData)

  ; save decoded file first, in case of crash
  tempfile := "tempfile.tmp"
  FileDelete, %tempfile%
  FileAppend, %decoded%, %tempfile%
  
  ; replace original
  FileDelete, %filepath%
  FileMove, %tempfile%, %filepath%
}
encodefile(filepath) {
  FileRead, rawData, %filepath%
  encoded := b64Encode(rawData)

  ; save encoded file first, in case of crash
  tempfile := "tempfile.tmp"
  FileDelete, %tempfile%
  FileAppend, %encoded%, %tempfile%
  
  ; replace original
  FileDelete, %filepath%
  FileMove, %tempfile%, %filepath%
}

;then you can simply read the ini file, like usual.
settingsfile := "myfile.ini"
decodefile(settingsfile )
IniRead, OutputVar, %settingsfile%, section, key

;on exit, save would look like this
settingsfile := "myfile.ini"
encodefile(settingsfile)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. However, what if the user finds the `.ini` file and alters the encoded information to "normal" readable information. For example, he changes the encoded information to just a string of `Hello World`. Will the Base64 script still be able to work?

Comment: @Dean No. The settings file would then be "corrupted": it would produce gibberish binary data.

Comment: If the user is able to change anything in there, there's simply no point in encoding it in my opinion.. :/

Comment: @Dean Like I said, a user will always be able to modify a file on their own system. Even if you used a DLL, you can still change it with things like ResHacker, ResEdit, etc. Anything else, could be considered to be malicious behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the point of storing information in a dll file just to hide it. Once the user looks at your code (and yes you can decompile ahk executables), he could simply copy the code required to alter the dll contents. Besides that he could probably just use resource hacker to modify it.
Consider using [RegWrite](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegWrite.htm) and [RegRead](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegRead.htm) if you don't want the information to be in a simple file. If you really think it gets you anywhere [store the data encrypted](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/90702-encrypt-decrypt-text/) and decrypt it when you read it.